# What am I implying with the expression: "Let's meet so we can get a better feel for each other" in a dating context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, dates

Just want to make sure I don't say something silly or nonsense. I am not a native speaker and the expression "have fun" is translated as "have fun" in all other language but in English is means let's have sex! Can someone give me the context of what this statement "Let's meet so we can get a better feel for each other" implies?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm behind the times, but I've never heard that _have fun_ is a euphemism for sex.

Comment: A better way to say that would be _so we can get to know each other_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some would say, half seriously, that everything translates to, "*let's have sex*" in the US. But they would be half wrong! In the dating context you describe ""*Let's meet so we can get a better feel for each other*" is most likely innocent of that charge and is a very common expression where the word "feel" means: to sense or perceive. So the import of the sentence is something like this: **Let's meet so we can get to know each other better**. In other words, *let us spend some time together so we can each get an improved understanding of each other*. Could be the start of  something beautiful! Best of luck. :-)

> **Feel** *verb*: feel; 3rd person present: feels; past tense: felt; past participle: felt; gerund or present participle: feeling
>
> **1**: ***be aware of*** (a person or object) through touching or being touched.
>   "she felt someone touch her shoulder"
>
> ***synonyms***: ***perceive***, ***sense***, detect, ***discern***, notice, ***be aware of***, be conscious of
>
> [Google](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=feel+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *[get a feel for](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/feel#feel)* is an idiomatic usage that means

> Familiarize oneself with:
>   *you can explore to get a feel of the place*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

The word *feel* has numerous meanings as both a verb and noun, many of them unrelated. This is just one of them. As you become more proficient in English, you will get a better feel for these nuances.